# Android facebook like button in webview not able to scroll down

Tags: android, facebook

I implemented facebook like button in my app. I followed this link

[developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button)

```
Settings.sdkInitialize(activity);
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);


likeView.setObjectId("//placed url link");

likeView.setForegroundColor(-256);
```

I'm not having facebook app on my device. When I click fb like button it opens on webview. But after that I'm not able to scroll down and my app is in landscape mode. 
[image]

Please suggest how I can fix this issue. I'm able to put like(Admin). I need to scroll , so the user is able to click on the like / unlike button.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. This seem to be a bug and hence it's best to report it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/). Note: we released a new SDK version and `setObjectId()` is no longer in use.

Comment: without setObjectId().. how to make.. Any link plz ?

Comment: The new sdk has a new method that can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#triggering). Yet I don't think this will solve your issue and hence it's better to create a bug report.